# function onclick javascript don't work in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've done a function onclick that download pdfs in our website. 
Everything works fine in Chrome and Mozilla except this ajax message (Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. )
But when i click there in Microsoft Edge, that don't work. Can anyone help me? My code is below.

```
<script>

function download_datasheet(uri, name) {



var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');  
            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];  
            var nome;  

            nome = name + ".pdf";  
            modal = document.getElementById('myModal');  
            modal_content = document.getElementsByClassName("modal_texto")[0];  
            lang = window.location.href;  
            lang = lang.split("/");  
            console.log(lang[1]);  
            if(lang[1].includes("pt-pt"))  
            modal_content.innerHTML =  "<table border=\"0\"><tr><td style=\"width:80px; background-color:white\"><img src=\"/sites/default/files/Imagens_tecit/Tecit/wait2.gif\" alt=\"wait\"></td><td style=\"background-color:white; color:#5cb8e5; font-size:20px;\"><p class=\"descricao\">Loading...</p></td></tr></table>"  
            else modal_content.innerHTML = "<table border=\"0\"><tr><td style=\"width:80px; background-color:white\"><img src=\"/sites/default/files/Imagens_tecit/Tecit/wait2.gif\" alt=\"wait\"></td><td style=\"background-color:white; color:#5cb8e5; font-size:20px;\"><p class=\"descricao\">Loading...</p></td></tr></table>"
            modal.style.display = "block";  

            var HttpClient = function() {  
                this.get = function(aUrl, aCallback) {  
                    var anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();    
                    anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { 
                        if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)  
                            aCallback(anHttpRequest);  
                    }  
                    console.log(aUrl);  
                    anHttpRequest.open( "GET", aUrl, true );          
                    XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials = false;  
                    anHttpRequest.send( null );  
                    anHttpRequest.responseType = "blob";  
                }
            }  

            var client = new HttpClient();  
            function eei_terminado(ficheiro){  
                var blob = new Blob([ficheiro.response]);  
                var a = document.createElement("a");  
                a.style = "display: none";  
                document.body.appendChild(a);  
                var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);  
                a.href = url;  
                a.download = nome;  
                a.click();  
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);  
                modal.style.display = "none";  
            }  
            client.get(uri, function(response) {  
                eei_terminado(response);  
            });


        }

</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does you test with `http://localhost`  url

Comment: it's a problem of browser compatibility... but yeah, i already tried on localhost.